# Creating new local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I'd like to create my own database, but I don't have any local server.

Can you guys help me create a local server?

Comment: If you only have to management tools installed you need to tun the installation again and add the database engine.

Comment: While installing `Sql server` you would have created a local instance why cant you use it

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL server installation again and while installing it will give you options to install features. Choose Only SQL Server as all other components you already have